# Another simple ode problem in a 1964 paper of Peter Lax

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Peter Lax start with simple results concerning solution of quadratic ode:
Let z(t) be the solution of the initial value problem;
$$dz/dt=a(t)z^2,\ \ \ z(0)=m$$
in the interval (0,T). Suppose that a(t) satisfies the inequality
$$|a(t)|<B;$$
then the initial value problem has a solution for |t|<|mB|^{-1}

Lax proof is following

let $z_1$ be the solution of the
$$dz_1/dt=Bz_1^2, z_1(0)=|m|$$
then $z_1(t)$ is upperbound for |z(t)| for all positive t. Q.E.D

Actually if we verify z1 be the upperbound for |z(t)|.

then if $m=0$, clearly $z_1(t)=0$, therefore z(t)=0, above arguement satisfy.

if $m\neq 0$,
$dz_1/dt=Bz_1^2\geq0$ therefore $z_1(t)=\int_0^t\frac{dz_1(\tau)}{d\tau} d\tau+z_1(0)\geq |m|>0$
therefore we can divide $z_1^2$ for both sides

therefore $z_1$ is always positive, $\frac{1}{z_1^2}\frac{dz_1}{dt}=B$, $-\frac{1}{z_1}+\frac{1}{|m|}=Bt$,$z_1=\frac{|m|}{1-|m|Bt}$

for $|t|<|mB|^{-1}$, $z_1=\frac{|m|}{1-|m|Bt}<\infty$, because $z_1$ is upperbound of $|z(t)|$ therefore $z(t)$ is also bounded for $|t|<|mB|^{-1}$

here is my question,

how can we verify, that $z_1$ is upperbound of $|z|$?

if we assume $z$ is not cross to x-axis, then we can divide $z^2$ to both side, $$1/z^2\frac{dz}{dt}=a(t)$$, $z=\frac{m}{1-m\int_0^ta(\tau)d\tau}$ then $|z|=\frac{|m|}{|1-m\int_0^ta(\tau)d\tau|}\leq\frac{|m|}{1-|m|\int_0^t|a(\tau)|d\tau}\leq z_1$

because $\int_0^t |a(\tau)d|\tau\leq \int_0^t B d\tau=Bt$

But for this we should divide $z^2$ to both sides, how we can believe $z$ is not zero at any time?

please give me some help!

Comment: $a(t)$ is not constant, the integral from its integration can not be resolved as multiplication with $t$.

Comment: that's my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $z(t)^{-2}z'(t)=a(t)$ you get
$$
\left|-z(t)^{-1}+m^{-1}\right|=\left|\int_0^ta(s)ds\right|
\le\int_0^t|a(s)|ds\le Bt
$$
Solving for $z(t)$ then gives directly
$$
1-|m|Bt\le mz(t)^{-1}\le 1+|m|Bt
\\~\\
\frac{1}{1-|m|Bt}\ge \frac{z(t)}{m}\ge\frac{1}{1+|m|Bt}
$$
For a non-zero solution, $z(t)/m$ is always positive, and as long as $1-|mB|t$ is positive, the left side provides an upper bound. Thus $z(t)$ can not diverge to infinity as long as $t<|mB|^{-1}$.

Comment: I always thanks to you, but I wonder you mean "non-zero solution" imply whether solution which are not cross x axis or 0 solution for all positive t.

Comment: Because of uniqueness, no solution can change its sign. Thus $z(t)/z(0)$ is always positive.

Comment: Actually, you start with $z (t)^{-2}$, for this, Isn't it necessary to assume that it doesn't cross the x-axis in (0,T)?

Comment: These are two slightly different conclusions from the same uniqueness statement.

Comment: I always appriciate your help, clearly I know $\frac{m}{1-m\int_0^ta(s)ds}$ is "a solution" for our IVP. But as far as I can accept, the part about the uniqueness of Ivp's solution is still unclear. Is there any more explicit proof for the uniqueness, for example, "suppose z(t) be the another solution (which are not zero solution, and different with $\frac{m}{1-m\int_0^ta(s)ds}$) which satisfy above IVP, then we get a contradiction ....."?